# Error: Attempt to invoke interface method

Tags: android-studio, cardview

Estoy usando Cardviews para una aplicacion y en esas CardView tengo dos botones que les quiero dar una funcion, el problema es que al dar clic en alguno de ellos me muestra el siguiente error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                                   Process:
>   com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa, PID:
>   22660
>                                                                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void
>   com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa.adapter.TareasAdapter$OnEventMovieListener.deleteMovie(int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                                                       at
>   com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa.adapter.TareasAdapter$UsuarioHolder.onClick(TareasAdapter.java:75)
>                                                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                                                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Asi se ve la interfaz que tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi clase donde recupero los botones es la siguiente:

```
package com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa.adapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Next University.
 */
public class TareasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TareasAdapter.UsuarioHolder>{

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Tareas> tareas;
    private List<Tareas> tarea;
    private OnEventMovieListener onEventMovieListener;

    //public MovieAdapter(List<Movie> movies) {
    //    this.movies = movies;
    //}
    public TareasAdapter(List<Tareas> tareas) {
        this.tarea = tareas;
    }

    public interface OnEventMovieListener {

        void changeDisponibilityMovie(Tareas tarea, boolean disponibility);

        void deleteMovie(int position);

        void actualizar(int position);
    }

    public TareasAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Tareas> tareas) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.tareas = tareas;
    }

    protected class UsuarioHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener, View.OnClickListener {

        protected TextView txtId, txtNombreUsuario, txtNota, txtEstudiante;

        Button btnDelete;
        Button btnUpdate;

        public UsuarioHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
            txtNombreUsuario = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_nombre_usuario);
            txtNota = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_nota);
            txtEstudiante = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtEstudiante);

            btnDelete = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnEliminar);
            btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);

            btnUpdate = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnActualizar);
            btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch(view.getId()){
                case R.id.btnEliminar:
                    onEventMovieListener.deleteMovie(getAdapterPosition());
                    break;
                case R.id.btnActualizar:
                    onEventMovieListener.actualizar(getAdapterPosition());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

        }
    }


    @Override
    public UsuarioHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.plantilla_usuariosegundo, parent, false);
        UsuarioHolder holder = new UsuarioHolder(view);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UsuarioHolder holder, int position) {
        //Movie movie = movies.get(position);
        //Tareas tarea = tareas.get(position);
        holder.txtId.setText("Codigo: "+ tareas.get(position).getId());
        holder.txtNombreUsuario.setText("Tarea: "+ tareas.get(position).getNombreTarea());
        holder.txtNota.setText("Nota: "+ tareas.get(position).getNota());
        holder.txtEstudiante.setText("Estudiante: "+ tareas.get(position).getEstudiante());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tareas.size();
    }

    public OnEventMovieListener getOnEventMovieListener() {
        return onEventMovieListener;
    }

    public void setOnEventMovieListener(
            OnEventMovieListener onEventMovieListener) {
        this.onEventMovieListener = onEventMovieListener;
    }
}
```

Y en esta clase es donde quiero usar mi metodo deleteMovie que es el metodo que debe de dispararse al momento de que yo presiono el boton de Eliminar:

```
package com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa;


import android.content.DialogInterface; import android.support.annotation.NonNull; import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView; import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction; import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat; import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout; import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle; import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog; import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle; import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager; import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView; import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar; import android.view.LayoutInflater; import android.view.MenuItem; import android.view.View; import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa.adapter.Asignatura; import com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa.adapter.AsignaturaAdapter; import com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa.adapter.Tareas; import com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa.adapter.TareasAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;

public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,TareasAdapter.OnEventMovieListener{

    AlertDialog alertDialog1;
    //private List<Movie> movies;
    //private MovieAdapter movieAdapter;
    private List<Tareas> tareas;
    private TareasAdapter tareasAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        //movies = new ArrayList<>();
        //movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(movies);
        //movieAdapter.setOnEventMovieListener(this);
        tareas = new ArrayList<>();
        tareasAdapter = new TareasAdapter(tareas);
        tareasAdapter.setOnEventMovieListener(this);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toolbar.setTitle("Control de Tareas");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("Asignaturas");

        asignaturaFragmento asignatura = new asignaturaFragmento();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.qwe, asignatura).commit();


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.asigna){

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setSubtitle("Asignaturas");
            asignaturaFragmento asignatura = new asignaturaFragmento();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.qwe, asignatura).commit();

        }else if(id == R.id.estudia){

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setSubtitle("Estudiantes");
            estudiantesFragmento estudiantes = new estudiantesFragmento();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.qwe, estudiantes).commit();


        }else if (id == R.id.tareas){
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setSubtitle("Tareas");
            tareasFragmento tareas = new tareasFragmento();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.qwe, tareas).commit();

        }
        //Este codigo nos permite mostrar que menu esta seleccionado
        //para poder identificar que menu esta en uso
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void changeDisponibilityMovie(Tareas tarea, boolean disponibility) {

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteMovie(int position) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Principal.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View MyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin_deletedonante, null);
        final int valor = position;
        builder.setView(MyView)
                .setPositiveButton("Eliminar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Boton positivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        alertDialog1.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Boton negativo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        alertDialog1.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog1 = builder.create();
        alertDialog1.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void actualizar(int position) {

    } }
```

Comment: Pudiste resolver el problema con el comentario que te dije de tu fragment?

Comment: @Andrespengineer No aun no, lo que se me ocurrio fue mandar a llamar a un metodo en mi fragmento, pero me sigue mandado error por un objeto null, no se como hacer una instanacia desde una clase a un metodo en un fragmento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo parece normal, pero el problema que ocasiona el `null` puede ser el siguiente.

- Intenta pasar la instancia que implementa la `interface` en el constructor del `adapter` y no con un método publico: esto suele ocurrir muchas veces y no encuentro la razón principal del porque ocurre.

Simplemente haz:

```
tareasAdapter = new TareasAdapter(tareas, this);
```

y en tu adapter, creas o modificas tu constructor:

```
public TareasAdapter(List<Tareas> tareas, OnEventMovieListener listener) {
        this.tarea = tareas;
        this.onEventMovieListener = listener;
}
```

Elimina los `Getter` and `Setter` de la interface de tu clase `TareasAdapter` y su usos.

Depura el programa en modo debug y asegúrate que el listener no llega `null`. Déjame saber si te funciono.

Comment: Ya lo intente como mencionas pero ahora recibo este error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa.adapter.TareasAdapter.setOnEventMovieListener(com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa.adapter.TareasAdapter$OnEventMovieListener)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.enriq.examen_tareas_segundo_plano_enrique_espinosa.tareasFragmento.onCreateView(tareasFragmento.java:61)

Comment: @EnriqueEspinosa Debes eliminar dicho metodo setOnEventMovieListener, tanto de tu activity, como de tu Adapter. Ya que no lo estas utilizando. Tanto el Getter como el Setter del listener.

Comment: @EnriqueEspinosa segun veo el error tienes un Fragment que implementaba la interfaz de la misma forma. En ese Fragment por igual debes pasar la instancia de la interfaz y eliminar los metodos. Dejame saber si te funciona.

Comment: No me funciono, sigo intentado con las modificaciones que mencionas pero aun no funciona, no se si hay otra forma de usar esos botones en otra clase

Comment: @EnriqueEspinosa Ese error que me pusiste en tu comentario es porque estas haciendo en la referencia de tu adapter setOnEventMovieListener(this); en alguna clase cuando tu adapter aun es null. Lo recomendable como te dije es eliminar el metodo setOnEventMovieListener de tu clase TareasAdapter y pasar el listener en el constructor new TareasAdapter(tareas, this); puedes mostrarme el codigo que hay en el onCreateView de tu Fragment que esta llamando dicho metodo en el adapter? se llama tareasFragmento. Edita la pregunta y agrega ese codigo si puedes.

Comment: @EnriqueEspinosa me notificas en cuanto agregues el codigo o hagas las respectivas modificaciones como te dije.

Comment: @Andrespenginner perdon por no responderte antes pero el equipo donde tengo el codigo no lo tengo con migo en fines de semana, estoy implementando la solucion que me diste pero sigue sin funcionar el codigo, envia algo nulo.

Comment: De echo intente con varias formas basandome en tu solucion pero no logro resolverlo, ahorita reinicie mis clase para volver a empezar

Comment: @EnriqueEspinosa Como te dije mi solución si resolvió tu problema. El problema ahora (el error que pusiste en este comentario) es porque no estas declarando tu adapter (new TareasAdapter), la instancia es nula. En tu fragment llamado tareasFragmento en el onCreateView, por ello al hacer setOnMovieListener te causa null. Si puedes aprueba la solución como correcta y reformula otra pregunta adjuntando tu codigo de tareasAdapter ya que es otro problema diferente al planteado.